# Passing around path dependent type fails to retain dependent value

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

Consider the following:

```
trait Platform {
  type Arch <: Architecture
  def parseArch(str: String): Option[Arch]
}

object Platform {
  def parse(str: String): Option[Platform] = ???
}

trait Architecture

def main() {
  def exec(p: Platform)(a: p.Arch) = ???

  Platform.parse("ios")
    .flatMap(p => p.parseArch("arm64").map(a => (p, a)))
    .flatMap { case (p, a) => exec(p)(a) } // <----- This fails to compile
}
```

`exec(p)(a)` fails to compile with error message:

> Error:(17, 40) type mismatch;
>     found   : a.type (with underlying type A$A2.this.Platform#Arch)
>     required: p.Arch
>       .flatMap { case (p, a) => exec(p)(a) }

From the error message, it seems that scalac fails to retain the value (`p`) on which `Arch` depends on and therefore it opts to type projection instead (although I'm not too sure what `A$A2.this`) means.

For what it's worth, substituting the last line with the following will compile:

```
.flatMap(p => exec(p)(p.parseArch("arm64").get))
```

Is this a limitation in scala compiler or perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The simple solution

Your best bet when dealing with path-dependent types is to always keep the owner value around, because Scala has very limited inference and reasoning power otherwise.

For example, your code example could be rewritten as:

```scala
Platform.parse("ios") flatMap {
   p => p.parseArch("arm64").map(exec(p))
}
```

It is generally possible to perform such rewritings, although the code will often become less concise and elegant. A common practice is to use dependent functions and parametric classes.

## Using dependent types

In your example, the code:

```
Platform.parse("ios").flatMap(p => p.parseArch("arm64").map(a => (p, a)))
```

has type `Option[(Platform, Platform#Arch)]`, because Scala's inference cannot retain the fact that the tuple's second element is dependent on the first element. (You get `A$A2.this.Platform` because you declared `Platform` in some inner context.)

In other words, Scala's `Tuple2` type is not dependent. We could correct that by making our own class:

```
case class DepPair(p: Platform)(a: p.Arch)
```

However, Scala does not support dependent class signatures yet, and it will not compile. Instead, we set to use a trait:

```
trait Dep {
  val plat: Platform
  val arch: plat.Arch
}
```

```scala
Platform.parse("ios")
  .flatMap { p => p.parseArch("arm64").map { a =>
    new Dep { val plat: p.type = p; val arch: p.Arch = a }}}
  .flatMap { dep => exec(dep.plat)(dep.arch) }
```

Notice the ascriptions on `val plat` and `val arch`, as without them, Scala will try to infer a refined type that will make type-checking fail.

We are in fact at the boundary of what is reasonable to do in Scala (IMHO). For example, if we had parametrized `trait Dep[P <: Platform]`, we would have gotten into all kinds of problems. Notably:

```
Error:(98, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : Platform => Option[Dep[p.type]] forSome { val p: Platform }
 required: Platform => Option[B]
```

Scala infers an existential function type, but what we'd like is actually to have the existential quantification *inside* the function type. We have to guide Scala to understand that, and we end up with something like:

```
Platform.parse("ios").flatMap[Dep[p.type] forSome { val p: Platform }]{
    case p => p.parseArch("arm64").map{case a: p.Arch =>
      new Dep[p.type] { val plat: p.type = p; val arch = a }}}
  .flatMap { dep => exec(dep.plat)(dep.arch) }
```

Now I'll let you decide which way is the best: stick with the owner `val` around (simple solution), or risk losing any sense of sanity you had left!

But talking about losing sanity and existentials, let's try and investigate a bit further...

## Using existentials (failed)

The problematic type of the intermediate result in your code was `Option[(Platform, Platform#Arch)]`.
There is actually a way to express it better, using an existential, as in:

```
Option[(p.type, p.Arch) forSome {val p: Platform}]
```

We can help Scala by specifying it explicitly, so the intermediate result has the intended type:

```
val tmp: Option[(p.type, p.Arch) forSome {val p: Platform}] =
  Platform.parse("ios")
  .flatMap { case p => p.parseArch("arm64").map { a => (p, a): (p.type, p.Arch) }}
```

However, we now touch a very sensitive area of Scala's type system, and it will often cause problems. In fact, I did not find a way to express the second `flatMap`...

Trying `tmp.flatMap { case (p, a) => exec(p)(a) }` gives the very helpful:

```
Error:(30, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type p.Arch)
 required: p.Arch
```

Another trial:

```
tmp.flatMap {
  (tup: (p.type, p.Arch) forSome {val p: Platform}) => exec(tup._1)(tup._2)
}
```

```scala
Error:(32, 79) type mismatch;
 found   : tup._2.type (with underlying type p.Arch)
 required: tup._1.Arch
```

At this point, I think any reasonable individual would give up -- and probably stay away from Scala programming for a few days ;-)

Comment: Intersting. I guess path-dependent types are still pretty rough around the edges in scala. After reading your answer, I've gave up on passing them in tuples (`trait` solution is interesting but a little too verbose) and instead made inner trait to hold reference to outer trait as shown below.  Thanks for approving my doubts.

Comment: Great. Note that you could make your `val platform` a `def platform`, so you do not have to keep an additional pointer to the outer trait (Scala already stores pointers to outer traits in inner traits).

Comment: Didn't know the difference between `def` and `val` involved pointer. Wouldn't `def` equally create pointer to whatever it refers to within its _closure_ (not sure if this is a thing in scala though)? Perhaps could you share a link?

Comment: I was just referring to the fact that in Scala, inner trait/classes usually keep a reference to their outer trait/class (useful for things like path-dependent pattern-matching). If you use reflection, you can see this field as something like `final private val p$1: Platform;`. If you add a `val` with the same content, it's going to add a redundant field `final private val platform: Platform`, whereas if it's just a `def` it won't introduce any field and will return the private field generated by Scala directly.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've learned to acknowledge the current limitation of scala compiler (as shown by *LP*'s answer), and instead came up with this workaround:

```
trait Platform {
  trait Architecture {
    val platform: Platform.this.type = Platform.this
  }

  object Architecture {
    def parse(str: String): Option[Architecture] = ???
  }
}

object Platform {
  def parse(str: String): Option[Platform] = ???
}

def main() {
  def exec(a: Platform#Architecture) = {
    val p = a.platform
    ???
  }

  Platform.parse("ios")
    .flatMap(p => p.parseArch("arm64"))
    .flatMap(a => exec(a))
}
```

Thankfully, inner trait can refer to outer trait in scala. This way, there is no need for passing around `p` and `p.Arch` together, instead every `a: Platform#Architecture` holds reference to its own `p: Platform`.